# How do you incorporate contributing to Stack Overflow into your schedule?

Tags: discussion

I'm trying to put more time into Stack Overflow, and I'm wondering - as a developer with a day job - how do *you* incorporate Stack Overflow into your schedule?

Comment: I quit my job to contribute to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ManojKumar do you work for SO now, or are you independently wealthy? :)

Comment: @patrickvacek I work for SO for free independent of wealth and never had a job to quit. :)

Comment: Id like to contribute more but I feel like all the *good* questions are either buried or been asked already. In short it used to be much easier to find a good question to answer back in the day; now it requires not just knowledge but time as well.

Answer (score 30):

StackOverflow for me is a displacement activity. I do it when I have a mental block on something more important or urgent, and I need a distraction. Unless things are really bad, in which case I might turn to Facebook.

Comment: yeah it's pretty nice if you need a context switch. And more useful than other things. You can help others and even learn new things with that.

Comment: Developers story will become the next Facebook soon.

Answer (score 24):

In short: whenever there is time.

---

It kind of depends. Usually you at some points have some "downtime" while working (when not doing pair programming or similar). Sometimes you can do other small projects but sometimes you know this downtime is only for a few minutes or not enough to do anything constructive inside your company. I usually then do a quick check on the tags I know I can contribute something and look at the most recent questions to see if there is something I can do.

*Well to be fair such "a few minutes" sometimes can turn into half an hour or so when you want to provide a quality answer and get lost in researching ;)*

Even when you cannot answer, you can upvote/downvote or flag questions when needed. Small things also help the community not only answers.

I don't force myself to be on Stack Overflow though. If I have things to do and no downtime in any way or I need to stay focused on the topic even with downtime, I avoid the context switch and may just not be on here for that time.

Comment: Yeah I tend to stay away from writing answers which still require research, too often I have to give up halfway through it because I simply have to get back to work :) But that leaves only the kind of questions which tend to already be duplicates. Having a job revolving around billable hours is a reputationless existence :)

Comment: @Gimby yeah I can see your point there. On the other side though when you have to do research yourself you are also learning things in the progress, which benefits you. I learned quite a few new things from stackoverflow by looking for questions I can answer.

Comment: Couldn't agree more, but that's more of a sales pitch to yourself to do go visit SO outside of working hours ;)

Comment: Also depends on the company how much educating yourself during downtime is tolerated / encouraged. At some places it's fine when you watch a cppcon talk while you have to wait 30 minutes for a build to finish to test it. But yeah, sales pitch ;)

Comment: @Gimby: When encountering such questions, I've marked them for later and then checked them back at home. Some time they've been answered by then and I have nothing to add, some time they've been answered but the present answers do not satisfy me and some time the OP is still waiting.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Nice and easy way to dedicate some home time within limits to SO. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 11):

The majority of my contributions happen during the following times:

1. When compiling or waiting for a master set of tests to pass.
2. That five minutes before a meeting when I'm not going to get something done anyways.
3. After I look up a question, sometimes I pause to give back right then and there.
4. On the train to/from work.

That said, I know that I'm bored at work or disengaged the minute my activity spikes. It's a good internal indicator to fix my situation.

Comment: #3 gets me often

Answer (score 6):

In addition the ways that other people mentioned, I frequently contribute to Stack Overflow (and other Stack Exchange sites) when I'm researching a problem purely for my own benefit.

For instance, the other day I finally got tired of Vim indenting HTML automatically. So I researched it until I finally worked out what was causing it, and [documented it](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/10129/7244).

Answer (score 0):

In my graduation time i was like coding +stackOverflow even i spent way too much time at so and so chat. Even i was kind of member of php chat room cv ring (i have casted app. 5k close and delete vote)Than with time things started to change which are.

1. I got some experience as well as knowledge so i find 9/10 users who ask questions do not even read documentation properly which frustrates me.
2. I dont like new updates in so website i loved old one a lot also i am getting bore from everything except chat where most of regulars  left.

So with time you lost interest in everything so you dont need to manage time. Also i never login while i am working i feel its kind of unethical we are not getting paid for writing answers here  its our personal affair.

Answer (score -27):

I don't. I visit it IF I can't fix something myself and would waste more time trying to solve than to look it up, or can share some interesting out-of-the-ordinary problem. Problem is: it's littered with old and/or incorrect stuff, which makes it a bit of a waste of time sometimes. On the other hand: I did learn some good stuff here and there. Mostly details or little irritating problems that need a hack. To really learn and master bigger topics and frameworks, you obviously go elsewhere.

Comment: *Problem is: it's littered with old and/or incorrect stuff, which makes it a bit of a waste of time sometimes.* Have you considered taking steps to alleviate or outright fix that old and incorrect stuff?

Comment: From time to time, one can make a contribution on here to indeed fix some obsolete or plain wrong advice. Doesn't make those posts or comments disappear though. The result is even longer posts and an endless list of remarks and answers, many of which are not correct or incomplete. That kills the whole benefit of what a site like this should bring: a fast and correct answer when someone is in a pickle and can't get out of it on their own. I understand where you are coming from, but it's still a bit of a naive remark.

Comment: Sorry to be so naive. There is an apparent contradiction in your argument, though: if (*if*) SO is about *bringing fast and correct answers when someone is in a pickle*, then some of the answers that helped people 5 years ago are probably out-of-date now... but they did a perfect job back then. Since we cannot predict the future, I believe you need to include time passing and technology marching on in your evaluation.

Comment: just indicating from your answer you just seem to be more like one using stackoverflow for information and not being one to provide information to the site. Nothing wrong with that but I kind of assume OP meant how this goes when you want to improve stackoverflow and "give back" to the community.

Comment: Frédéric Hamidi: obviously you are right there. Many answers did do a great job back then, and are not so great anymore and mis-inform people now. And so we are back to the core problem. And flowing that into what Hayt said: sure it's a bit of the point that the community on SO gives back. No problem there, nothing against that. Now, lately, I try to be a bit more involved, and try to give answers myself. I only asked about 3/4 questions on here though, and if you go check those out, you will notice that eventually, I found the solution myself and shared it here (giving back ;))

Comment: Loving it.  It's always the same old folk with 10 million rep answering on here.  Dude with 58 rep coming out of left field with a flame thrower, we need more of this kind of thing.

Comment: Also: SO taking the "easier" path and mostly handing the responsibility of updating ALL info and answers on the site to the current technology to the community itself is a bit of a cop-out. Now, that itself wouldn't be a disaster if it was working. But it isn't. So in short, I think they should try to do more themselves as well.

But yes Hayt, I do agree fully with the fact that more people getting help from users on SO, should also give back and contribute. Myself included. Trying to do that more now, in at least the same degree that I got help here.

Comment: You don't have to though. But if you feel yourself like you should go ahead. It's like with open source etc though. You have many users who never contribute and a "few" who do though. I guess the question though was about how you incorporate working full time and giving back to stackoverflow at the same time.

Comment: McNab: much appreciated. Now, I don't say that stuff to start problems with anyone. Most of my learning is done from either sites like pluralsight (which is obviously not free, but brings you the latest up to date, tried & tested stuff) or from experience and some tutorials here and there. As I said, to me SO is handy for some nasty details I can't sort out and other people have messed with as well. But of course, those are often the ones with the most comments and suggestions, most of which are wrong.

Comment: Hayt, concerning the actual topic: I guess most would be like me. You have work, you have stuff to DO and deadlines to meet instead of spending hours and hours adding answers, inspecting previous answers and so on. We visit SO because we've been messing about with something and want to now get an answer because we have managers breathing down our necks. Once you found the answer, you're not going to spend a whole lot of extra time on here, you want to get on with your work. You upvote an answer as the right one (giving back). A community can't do it all AND work fulltime on other stuff too ;)

Comment: That's why nobody will blame you for not being able to contribute. I guess a lot of the people on here (even the ones contributing) have stuff to do. Though sometimes people have some downtime. And instead of doing something non-constructive people could also "browse" stackoverflow. And the more reputation you get the more there is to do for you. But yeah that's what makes stackoverflow so good. Up and downvotes are actually important and when you at least leave an upvote when an answer has helped you, you award the person who did the work for the answer and maybe he will answer more.

Comment: You're right. Being able to help is very nice, and does improve your own skills as well. People just have to realize that most people are selfish and will not contribute, and secondly: it takes time to contribute.

Trying hard though ;)

Comment: @Hayt yup. That's what I meant

Comment: This answer has absolutely nothing to do with the question asked, And seems to be based on a misconception of the wording of the question. The question is asking how Stack Overflow **contributors** *schedule* their time appropriately to be able to spend more time **contributing** while also having a full time development job. This answer is about.... nothing relevant.

Comment: Another reason not to post too much here: the SO Police

Comment: Seriously? You don't like incomplete answers that don't answer the question, remarks, etc. Then you go and post an incomplete answer that doesn't answer the question, and you complain about people telling you that your answer doesn't answer the question? Good luck with that.

Comment: If you do have the time, please feel free to leave comments on incorrect answers, and especially to downvote them (if you make it to the point of gaining the ability to downvote)!

Comment: @JoshCaswell Comments can be helpful on *obsolete* answers as well. Though I wouldn't downvote such an answer if it was useful and accurate at the time it was posted. Also, older versions of languages, libraries and programs can remain in use for quite some time.

Comment: "Obsolete" information is far less a problem than you make it out to be, assuming that there is a reasonable search function. Since Google has solved that problem for the Internet pretty much definitively, I'd say that this is a non-issue. Sure, we've lots of old Q&A about deprecated and "obsolete" technologies. But as you said, this information was *once* quite useful to you, and it is still definitely useful to a small subset of people tasked with maintaining legacy systems. If you need *new* information, ask a new question. If you're browsing simply to learn new stuff, you only see new Q&A.

Comment: "_To really learn and master bigger topics and frameworks, you obviously go elsewhere_." You're right that you won't master a topic just by _reading_ SO posts—as you pointed out the site is for Q&A, it's not a textbook. But as you start answering more and more questions, and explaining topics to other people, and doing the research to support your posts, you'll find yourself developing more in-depth knowledge and expertise than you would get through almost any other medium.

Comment: [Wow, the irony!](https://frinkiac.com/gif/S11E09/672960/675160.gif?b64lines=IAogVEhFIElST05JTkcgSVMgREVMSUNJT1VTLg==)